# Not able to add column to Databricks dataframe using withColumn but schema reflects the additional column

Tags: sql, pyspark, schema, databricks

Trying to add an extra 2 columns into my databricks pyspark dataframe but it doesn't show up when I select * from the resulting table.

```
for file in file_list:
  
  try:
    sql_query = create_sql_statement(file)
    df = spark.sql(sql_query) \
    .withColumn('type', F.lit('animal_type')) \
    .withColumn('timestamp', F.current_timestamp())
    df.write.format("delta").option("overwriteSchema", "true").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(f'{database}.{table}')

  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Example of create_sql_statement: 'CREATE TABLE database.TABLE_NAME AS SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, type, timestamp FROM DATABASE.TABLENAME'

When running the code above, the for loop successfully creates the table and I see the pyspark df result below but don't see the new columns implemented in my table.

```
num_affected_rows:long
num_inserted_rows:long
type:string
timestamp:timestamp
```

I see one of two results:

1. When I select * from one of the tables, I see the result 'query returned no results', but if I select * from the source database.table_name the create_sql_statement is built from, there is definitely data there.
2. Depending on the table, for some when I select * I see the correct output but without the added columns from the 'withColumn' clauses above.

Am I missing something on the syntax? This is a followup question from my previous question 'SQL Error mismatched input 'sql_query' expecting {EOF} when using Create Table in Pyspark' which was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points:

- A `CREATE TABLE...` statement will not return the resulting table. So when you run `spark.sql(sql_query)` it returns nothing... which you then try to modify and have chosen to ignore the ensuing error.
- You can't overwrite a table you're currently reading from. It's not clear if this is what you're trying to do or not.

What you likely mean to do is:

```
df = spark.sql(
    """
    SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4 
      FROM DATABASE.table_you_read_from
    """
)
df = (
    df.withColumn('type', F.lit('animal_type'))
      .withColumn('timestamp', F.current_timestamp())
)
(
    df.write
      .format("delta")
      .option("overwriteSchema", "true")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .saveAsTable('DATABASE.new_table')
)
```

Alternatively, in pure SQL this would be:

```
spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DATABASE.new_table")
spark.sql(
    """
    CREATE TABLE DATABASE.new_table AS
    SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4
         , 'animal_type' AS type
         , current_timestamp AS timestamp
      FROM DATABASE.table_you_read_from
    """
)
```

Comment: Your first option works perfectly. Thank you for your patient understanding of my noob-ness and for all of your help!

Comment: One follow-up question: I'm assuming 'num_affected_rows:long' is part of the error message you mention, but what does this part mean? And to answer your comment #2, your assumption above when defining df is correct. the first statement is the table_read_from and the second is the new_table. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: It may not be strictly true that `spark.sql("CREATE TABLE...")` returns nothing, but rather returns some information about the created, or attempted to create, table. I can't be sure without seeing the error message though.

Comment: I see. I only saw this message which probably indicates exactly what you said about returning information about the table that pyspark attempted to create. Thank you again for your help! Error message which technically is the new schema: num_affected_rows:long
num_inserted_rows:long
type:string
timestamp:timestamp